# Edit UILable, hide inputAccessoryView [swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uilabel, inputaccessoryview

Help me solve this problem.
I have a tableView, the cells contain UILable
I need to show the keyboard with inputAccessoryView (with textField) when taping a cell or lable.
After editing, pass the text from textField to UILable in the cell, close the keyboard and completely hide inputAccessoryView.

Now I'm solving this problem with inputAccessoryView, I textField.becomeFirstResponder(), but after editing inputAccessoryView remains visible.

!!! I need inputAccessoryView to be completely hidden before and after editing. Not on the screen. now before and after editing it is at the bottom of the screen

[prior to editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pucX7.png)

[during editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z8qt.png)

[once edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IGn3.png)

Here's my code.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var customInputView: UIView!
    var sendButton: UIButton!
    var addMediaButtom: UIButton!
    let textField = FlexibleTextView()


    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {

        if customInputView == nil {
            customInputView = CustomView()
            customInputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
            textField.placeholder = "I'm gonna grow in height."
            textField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5

            customInputView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

            customInputView.addSubview(textField)

            sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
            sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
            sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
            sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
            customInputView?.addSubview(sendButton)

            addMediaButtom = UIButton(type: .custom)
            addMediaButtom.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "addImage").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
            addMediaButtom.isEnabled = true
            //addMediaButtom.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
           // addMediaButtom.setTitle("Media", for: .normal)
            addMediaButtom.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 9, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 0)
            addMediaButtom.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside) 
            customInputView?.addSubview(addMediaButtom)

            textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addMediaButtom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sendButton.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal)
            sendButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal)

            addMediaButtom.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal)
            addMediaButtom.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal)

            textField.maxHeight = 80

            addMediaButtom.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 8
                ).isActive = true

            addMediaButtom.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: textField.leadingAnchor,
                constant: -8
                ).isActive = true

          /*  addMediaButtom.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.topAnchor,
                constant: 8
                ).isActive = true
            */
            addMediaButtom.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
                constant: -8
                ).isActive = true

            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: sendButton.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 0
                ).isActive = true

            textField.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.topAnchor,
                constant: 8
                ).isActive = true

            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
                constant: -8
                ).isActive = true

            sendButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor,
                constant: 0
                ).isActive = true

            sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -8
                ).isActive = true

            sendButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: customInputView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
                constant: -8
                ).isActive = true
        }
        return customInputView
    }

    @objc func handleSend() {
        print("works")

        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
         self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 0

    }




    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}

class CustomView: UIView {

    // this is needed so that the inputAccesoryView is properly sized from the auto layout constraints
    // actual value is not important

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Your before and after images appear identical? So it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I need inputAccessoryView to be completely hidden before and after editing. Not on the screen. now before and after editing it is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Didn't you try to create the view and save it in some global variable? And in real time use `inputAccessoryView = nil`, and `inputAccessoryView = customView`

Comment: of course I tried! But... You can hide inputAccessoryView = nil, but you cannot add it again. How do I return it, for example, by pressing the ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `inputAccessoryView` for every textfield. Than it will appear only when you inputting text via current textfield.

To set it use:

```
textfield.inputAccessoryView = customView
```

If you want to remove it exactly use it (but it's unnecessary)

```
textfield.inputAccessoryView = nil
```

to hide it.

P.S. It's better to create the difficult view via xib-view.

Comment: I hide inputAccessoryView = nil, but I cannot add it again. How do I get it back when I tap a cell ?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the accessory view when you tap the "Send" button, you need to prevent the tableView from becoming first responder again.

Add this to your class:

```
var bEditing: Bool = false
```

then change `canBecomeFirstResponder()` and `handleSend()`:

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return !bEditing
}

@objc func handleSend() {
    print("works")

    bEditing = true
    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

    bEditing = false
}
```